# V8 BigInt size in memory?

Tags: node.js, v8, bigint

Is there a way to get the occupied memory size in bytes of BigInt numbers?

```
let a = BigInt(99999n)
console.log(a.length) // yield undefined
```

Thanks

Comment: BigInt doesn't has length property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: @cosmin_popescu: exactly, so how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 12):

V8 developer here. There is generally no way to determine the occupied memory size of an object, and BigInts are no exception. Why do you want to access it?

As far as the internal implementation in V8 is concerned, a BigInt has a small object header (currently two pointer sizes; this might change over time), and then a bit for every bit of the BigInt, rounded up to multiples of a pointer size. 99999 is a 17-bit number, so in your example `let a = 99999n` ("`BigInt(99999n)`" is superfluous!), the allocated BigInt will consume `(2 + Math.ceil(17/64)) * 64 bits === 24 bytes` on a 64-bit system.

It may or may not make sense to add length-related properties or methods (`.bitLength`?) to BigInts in the future. If you have a use case, I suggest you file an issue at https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues so that it can be discussed.

Comment: Thanks but I took that value as an example, it can be anything. I will use the BigInt to buffer node extension

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need to know BigInts' sizes in memory?